# The remove of individual Marker from Map and List, together

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

In my application I have an `ArrayList` markers, exactly:

```
   public ArrayList<Marker> listMarker = new ArrayList<Marker>();
    public int p = listMarker.size();
    public Marker singleMarker;
```

I put markers in `ArrayList` as follows:

```
MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng);
 listMarker.add(p, singleMarker = nMap.addMarker(options));
```

I was looking for at site the same problem and I have not found
Now I try to do that every button click will remove the last marker from the map and list. If I have 5 markers that click is 4, the next click is 3 and so on. But not only from the list, and also from the map, the biggest problem

My attempt that does not work like this:

```
deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View view) {

        listMarker.remove(k);

    }
});
```

Button is not removed `Marker` from the map. I suspect that this only removes the last marker from the list but no from the map and do not know how to deal with it.

Comment: This is very unclear.  It's hard to tell what the issue is, or what you're asking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you are only removing the marker from the List, the Map is going to hold onto it until you explicitly remove it... Call remove on the Marker to remove it from the map, like so:

```
deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (listMarker != null && !listMarker.isEmpty()) {
            listMarker.get(k).remove(); // Add this line
            listMarker.remove(k);
        }    
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried to do a few hours, thanks !
Now when i dont have on map Markers and i click the button, i get error: "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0" . You know how to fix it?

Comment: Add a simple check to see if the list is empty before removing; see updated code. I encourage you to do a bit more learning before asking further questions on Stackoverflow, as these are rather basic and specific things... you will gain much deeper knowledge through some self-investigation!

Comment: ups, i update code and still get "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0"

Comment: Hmm are you sure you copied the code properly? If the list size was 0 as the error says, !listMarker.isEmpty() would return false, so it shouldn't try to remove the marker.

Comment: Ah, it happens. No worries!